# Json to deserialized usable object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to convert this json into an object. So far I have the following:

```
{
    "DebugCategories":
    {
        "GameDebugNode":
        {
            "MatchFitterDebugNode": 
            {
                "EnableDisableFitter": true,
                "SetFitter": ["Reset to None", "100 Remain", "30 Remain", "15 Remain", "5 Remain"]
            },
            "LookDebugNode":
            {
            }
        },
        "ChickensDebugNode":
        {
        },          
    }
}
```

And using json 2 c# website, this is what I have (without set/gets):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class DebugJsonController {
    public DebugCategories DebugCategory;

    [Serializable]
    public class MatchFitterDebugNode {
        public bool EnableDisableFitter;
        public List<string> SetFitter;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class LookDebugNode
    {
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class GameDebugNode {
        public MatchFitterDebugNode MatchFitterDebugNode;
        public LookDebugNode LookDebugNode;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class ChickensDebugNode
    {
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class DebugCategories {
        public GameDebugNode GameDebugMode;
        public ChickensDebugNode ChickensDebugMode;
    }
}
```

Then I do the following:

```
var debugManifest = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("DebugData");
DebugJsonController ro = JsonUtility.FromJson<DebugJsonController>(debugManifest.text);
```

`ro` contains `DebugCategories` but within that, everything else is null i.e. the `GameDebugNode` and `ChickensDebugNode`.

So I'm not entirely sure why it's not converting correctly... any help? I'm using Unity to load in the json file into text.

Comment: Unity's JSON doesn't work the same as C#'s JSON. The C# generated by the utility assumes C#, not Unity. Unity's JsonUtility does not work with getters/setters well, so just convert them to public fields instead of properties and try it that way.

Comment: I know they are different, hence why they don't have any getters/setters. That's why I said that i've taken them out, however the 2 items I mentioned still come back as null

Comment: I misunderstood and thought you removed them for this post only. It may also be with it being nested classes. I know it took a lot of fiddling when I tried Unity's `JsonUtility`. Unity's JSON is incredibly "simple", a little disappointing they didn't use Newtonsoft's and rolled their own.

Comment: Make sure the field *names* match the properties of the Json, you have named the `DebugCategories` property in the json as `DebugCategory` in your objects. This: `public DebugCategories DebugCategory;` creates a field with the name `DebugCategory` using the type `DebugCategories`, and this does not match the json.

Comment: To make your json and code easier to read, make sure indentation is actually correct, it's very hard to read as you've posted it.

Comment: Also, arrays (and I think `List<T>`) is not supported in `JsonUtility`, you can search for work-arounds but they aren't pretty.

Comment: Really? `List<T>` isn't supported? God... what has the world come to...

Comment: Sorry @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, i tried correcting the indentation, from what I can see it was only the last curly braces that were not indented so it should not have been that hard to read...

Comment: Even making sure all names match and removing the List it still doesn't work :( still all null

Comment: Maybe doing `var debugManifest = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("DebugData");` this line is causing the issue?

Comment: Problem solved. This now works. 
`string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/DebugData.json"); 
   DebugJsonController ro = JsonUtility.FromJson<DebugJsonController>(jsonString);` Well that was annoying...

Comment: @sushi7777 `List<T>` isn't supported by JsonUtility because Unity decided to optimize JsonUtility to serialize Unity data types.

Comment: Hmm seems to work though. It populates the List<T> correctly. I'm using Unity 2019 1.0f2 btw. But yeah... seems to work fine

Comment: @sushi7777 Lists are supported.... Dictionaries however are not. Lists are just arrays in a fancy wrapping.